# Disable carriage return in onload javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web form that uses a check box function.  Users are bypassing the consent checkbox, however, as you can just hit a hard return after entering your creds.  Trying to get something that will restrict the carriage return bypassing the check box...

```
function consentCheckBoxChecked() {
    debugger;
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("consentCheckBox");

    if (checkBox.checked === true) {
        submitBtn.classList.remove("is-disabled");
    } else {
        submitBtn.classList.add("is-disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add/remove the "disabled" attribute to/from the submit button.

Comment: your title and question are not related though

Comment: In the "onchange" event handler of the checkbox, you can toggle the disabled state of the submit button: `submitBtn.toggleAttribute("disabled", !checkBox.checked);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this, in addition to applying required classes

```
<body onload="OnLoadEvent();">

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function OnLoadEvent() {
    document.getElementById("submitButton").Enabled = false;
}

function consentCheckBoxChecked()
{
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("consentCheckBox");

    if (checkBox.checked) {
        submitBtn.Enabled = true;
    } else {
        submitBtn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```